# How do I force the AWS .NET SDK to utilize the us-east-1 regional endpoint for S3 rather than the legacy global endpoint?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When utilizing the .Net AWS SDK for S3, I've noticed that by default when talking to a bucket in us-east-1, that it is utilizing the legacy global endpoint `BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com` rather then the regional endpoint `BUCKETNAME.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

How do I force the SDK to utilize the regional endpoint?

Example .Net 6 code:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.S3;

AmazonS3Config config = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config();
config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");

Console.WriteLine($"S3 Client Service URL: {config.DetermineServiceURL()}");
```

> S3 Client Service URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tell the client to explicitly utilize the regional endpoint rather than the legacy global endpoint which is the default.

```
config.USEast1RegionalEndpointValue = S3UsEast1RegionalEndpointValue.Regional;
```

By modifying the code with this change:

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.S3;

AmazonS3Config config = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config();
config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");

config.USEast1RegionalEndpointValue = S3UsEast1RegionalEndpointValue.Regional;

Console.WriteLine($"S3 Client Service URL: {config.DetermineServiceURL()}");
```

You now get the regional endpoint service url:

> S3 Client Service URL: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 1):

To send the `us-east-1` S3 requests to the regional endpoint, set the [`USEast1RegionalEndpointValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TS3UsEast1RegionalEndpointValue.html) property on the `AmazonS3Config` object to `S3UsEast1RegionalEndpointValue.Regional`.

This will force the routing of `us-east-1` S3 requests to the regional endpoint instead of the legacy global endpoint.

```cs
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.S3;

AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    USEast1RegionalEndpointValue = S3UsEast1RegionalEndpointValue.Regional,
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
};

Console.WriteLine($"S3 Client Service URL: {config.DetermineServiceURL()}");
```

```
S3 Client Service URL: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

---

`GetPreSignedURL` example for the `us-east-1` region using the regional endpoint:

```cs
var bucketName = "your-bucket-name";

var amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
    USEast1RegionalEndpointValue = S3UsEast1RegionalEndpointValue.Regional
};

using var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(amazonS3Config);

var objectKey = "your-object-key";

var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = objectKey,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
};

var preSignedUrl = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);

Console.WriteLine("Pre-signed URL: " + preSignedUrl);
```

```
Pre-signed URL: https://your-bucket-name.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-object-key?AWSAccessKeyId=xxx&Expires=xxx&Signature=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more easily if you simply pass the appropriate region to the S3 client object's constructor. For example:

`_s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);`