# Force AWS .net SDK to include region in presigned S3 URLs

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

When I make a call to `GetPreSignedURL` using the C# S3 SDK (version 3.7.204.1), I get an endpoint host of "bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com" if the bucket exists in us-east-1. If I make the same call with the `aws cli presign` (version 2.13.14), I get the scheme "bucket-name.s3.**region**.amazonaws.com". The latter is what I want so that it is uniform across regions. How do I tell the SDK to include the region even if it's us-east-1 so that it matches the output of the AWS CLI? I've tried explicitly setting the `RegionEndpoint` when creating the S3Client as well as setting `AWSConfigsS3.UseSignatureVersion4 = true;` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369427/how-to-generate-aws-s3-pre-signed-url-using-signature-version-4).

(Yes, the signatures produced by `sdk` are valid, but for reasons I don't feel like going into, I have to be able to use both `cli` and `sdk` and have them give the same host for S3.)

Comment: Deja vu! Check: [How do I force the AWS .NET SDK to utilize the us-east-1 regional endpoint for S3 rather than the legacy global endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566672/4800344)